# Query builder with select

Tags: join, model, phalcon

I am trying to select some columns from a join result. The query is:

```
$queryBuilder = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder();
$queryBuilder->columns(array('L.*', 'S.build_id'));
$queryBuilder->addFrom('Gadwin\Models\Licenses', 'L');
$queryBuilder->join('Gadwin\Models\Serials', 'S.id = L.serial_id', 'S');
$resultset = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

If i remove the columns method, the query works and return a Licenses collection. But, if i set the columns method, an empty array is returned.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of query builder, try [raw sql](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#using-raw-sql) in phalcon.

create one method in your model.

```
public function myRawSql()
{
  $query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE some_condition";
  $modelObj = new ModelName(); // Create object of your model
  return $modelObj->getReadConnection()->query($query)->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you ask for results from 2 Tables. In this case, Phalcon will return a ComplexResultSet, instead of a ResultSet. Try a get_class on your $resultset, and if it is a ComplexResultSet, you can iterate it to access its rows. It should be something like:

```
----------------------------------
| Licence (object) | s.id (int ) |
----------------------------------
| Licence (object) | s.id (int ) |
----------------------------------
```

Generally, try also using a debugging tool such as Kint to examine your variables. It can be very helpful.